# Why is this mySQL UPDATE not making changes?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, sql-update

I know nothing about mySQL. A friend and I are struggling with this tiny bit of code.

### Background:

I'm trying to solve an issue I have with character encoding on my WordPress database. My original WordPress database is `wordpress`, and the modified database is `wordpress2` (which exists largely as a copy of the original). I want to select the `post_content` of a single entry in `wordpress`, convert it to utf8, and insert it into the corresponding row in `wordpress2`.

### The Script:

```
update wordpress2.wp_posts wp2 
   set wp2.post_content = (select convert(wp.post_content using utf8)
                             from wordpress.wp_posts wp
                            where wp.ID = wp2.ID )
 where wp2.ID = 789;
```

### When run:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Why isn't this changing any rows? What do we need to do to make it do so?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe the sub-query needs an alias as well.

Comment: Are you sure the values are not the same already?

Comment: "matched 1, changed 0" implies the row already has the value it would be changed to. An update does not actually occur if the new value does not differ from the old one.

Comment: Oops, @zerkms is correct. The two values were already the same. I suppose, in hindsight, that should have been obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, as @zerkms first pointed out [in the comments above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799021/why-is-this-mysql-update-not-making-changes#comment45872326_28799021), was that the values were already identical.